# running angular after the whole page is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run this angular app in a partial view, then it should run just right after the whole page (this partial view with every other partial views) is loaded.
Normally I would do this with `window.onload`, but it's not possible to do the same thing with angular, because obviously it'll say the app is not defined:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var gmatApp = angular.module('gmatApp', []);    
    gmatApp.controller('gmat_ctrl', function ($scope) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Is there any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bootstrap [angular manually](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap). Load the angular code (including app module) normally, but before the onload handler. Don't use ng-app on the partial, and define an id on it. This should be the onload handler:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var appArea = document.getElementById('id of appArea');
    angular.bootstrap(appArea , ['gmatApp']);
}
```